# What causes a split in the ummah for a sect to be created?

Tags: sects

Just for context, I did take a look at this question: [What defines a sect in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/what-defines-a-sect-in-islam).

However, I am asking on this: **What makes a sect in Islam a sect?**

For example, could anyone say, "I think we should do this instead of what the Sunni do" then that person creates a sect. Or is it as simple as that, or more in depth like sects have to be based on something?

Comment: Found my answer here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10818/37617

Comment: You may mark that post as a duplicate if you think it answers your question!

Comment: @Medi1Saif didn't know we could mark our own posts duplicate. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: You are welcome! Better you do it than I do it and it comes out it was a misunderstanding.